# how to set the routing translation based on annotation?

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations, translation

All the routing of my website is realized based on the annotations. Now, I want to translate my routing. To realize that, I tried to use the bundle [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle).

Nevetheless, the documentation does not give any example how to specify the route for each locale.

This is an action with its routing, how to translate it?

```
/**
 * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome")
 * @Template()
 */
public function welcomeAction() {
    return array();
}
```

Thanks,

---

## Question after being edited

```
/**
 * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome", defaults={"_locale" = "en"})
 * @Route("/bienvenue", name="welcome", defaults={"_locale" = "fr"})
 * @Route("/willkommen", name="welcome", defaults={"_locale" = "de"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function welcomeAction() {
    return array();
}
```

Now, what is happening with this new annotations:

1. the selected route is always the last one which is `/willkommen` (if you change the order the routes, the selected route is still the last one)
2. the `_locale` is set the the locale of the last route which 'de' according to the annotation above.

So, any proposal?
Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried `* @Route("/welcome", name="welcome", locale="fr")`?

Comment: For the people using Symfony 3.0: I think the JMSI18nRoutingBundle does not work for Symfony 3.0+... Same goes for the BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle.. Stick to Symfony 2.8 for now if you would like to make use of routing translations..

Comment: I am still using symfony 2.8. In addition, some bundles I am using are not ready for symfony 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You just have to set run the following command

> php app/console translation:extract fr --bundle=MinnTestBundle 
>   --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --output-format=yml

Then, `minn/TestBundle/Ressources/translations/routes.fr.yml` file will be generated. Customize you route translations & that is it!

Hope it will help others...

Comment: After having the translation files? How can you set the Route to be translation in the annotation? * @Route("route_about", name="website_about"). For example route_about is in my translation files. But the url is route_about and does not get translated...

Comment: in your controller, you set just set the route for your default locale. In the translation file, you will have to edit the translated route! It is straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple route annotations.

```
/**
 * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome", defaults={"_locale" = "en"})
 * @Route("/bienvenue", name="welcome", defaults={"_locale" = "fr"})
 * @Template()
 */
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which is working but not 100%. So, 2 questions: the answer your proposed works with ** JMSI18nRoutingBundle**? Would JMSI18nRoutingBundle some conflict with **LuneticsLocaleBundle**?

Comment: It should work with the JMSI18nRoutingBundle as this is code from Symfony core. I don't know anything about LuneticsLocaleBundle, sorry.

Comment: thank you again. one more question: is it possible to have two different routes having the same name (as you gave me in the example)?

Comment: to summarize what happens with your proposed solution is: **(1)** the last route is always selected (for your proposal, it is `/bienvenue`), **(2)** it set the la `_locale` of the last route (for your proposal, it is `fr`). Any ideas? Thanks!