# How to use multiple routes to one controllerAction with Symfony3

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony

I would like to configure multiple URLs to one Action in Controller (internationalization purposes).

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301294/how-to-set-the-routing-translation-based-on-annotation) it was surely possible in symfony2 to:

1. Make double annotation route.
2. Use 3rd party Bundle (for example "[BeSimple's](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle)").

But I'm **using Symfony 3.0.3** which prohibits me from doing so until I change the route's name (example):

```
/**
 * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome", defaults={"_locale" = "en"})
 * @Route("/bienvenue", name="welcomeFR", defaults={"_locale" = "fr"})
 * @Route("/willkommen", name="welcomeDE", defaults={"_locale" = "de"})
 */
```

But adding additional "FR/DE" chars to routes change their presence and ruins my URL generating logic in template, I'm forced to make on all links:

```
{# homepage example #}

{% if _locale = 'en' %}
   {{ path('welcome') }}   {# Routes from set only for "en" #}
{% elseif _locale = 'fr' %}
   {{ path('welcomeFR') }} {# "fr" only links #}
{% endif %} {# and so on #}
```

Anyone found the proper solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting 10 hours on finding solution on Symfony3 I've made those assumptions:

- None of the route trick with exactly same "name" **wouldn't work**,

Any kind like double annotation, double "routing.yml" importing, host based matching gives the same effect - **only one route is matched**, usually the last one. Would be ("/willkommen", name="welcomeDE") in my example.

- Both of the i18n bundles **does not work** on Symfony3 through the versioning constraints,

Composer wouldn't even let us install the bundle.

- Locale Listener and Loader (Routing Component) **is dying on caching**.

My solution to match the "_locale" and pass it to the LocaleLoader in order to load "routing_en.yml/routing_fr.yml" etc. files respectively is cached on the first match by the Symfony and after that, changing the "_locale" does not affect route's mapping.

## In conclusion

Symfony3 seems not supporting route "example" with more than one "url" at all. Through the constraints and caching.

After the disappointment I'm considering going back to Symfony 2.8, **have no idea what was pointing Symony's masters to block "double annotation" solution and what is their current idea on links internationalization**.

Hope someday it will be possible to achieve with S3, as link i18n is quite common SEO practice.

***EDIT:** Confirmed, working like a charm on 2.8.5 with BeSimple's i18n.*

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is the preferred way to point multiple routes to an unique controller action. So, your current problem is to regenerate the current path, depending on which route is being used

Maybe you don't have to modify your logic if you use {{ app.request.get('_route') }} to get the name of your current routing. This way, you could use:

```
{{ path(app.request.get('_route')) }}
```

---

UPDATE:

What about create an action per route and forwarding them to the main language action? Maybe it is not the best practice, but could work fine

```
/**
 * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome", defaults={"_locale" = "en"})
 */
public function welcomeAction()
{
    /* code here */
}
/**
 * @Route("/bienvenue", name="welcomeFR", defaults={"_locale" = "fr"})
 */
public function welcomeFrAction()
{
    $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:ControllerName:welcome');
}

/*
 * @Route("/willkommen", name="welcomeDE", defaults={"_locale" = "de"})
 */
public function welcomeDeAction()
{
    $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:ControllerName:welcome');
}
```

Comment: That's tricky and quite nice solution, thanks. But unfortunately it would not recognize that other routes should be also localized (e.g. route "welcomeAnotherName" matched wouldn't determine {"_locale" = "fr"} on all of the rest routes.

Comment: I'm looking into "Routing Component" and "custom Route Loader", maybe I will find there simple solution for determining set of links by the "_locale".

Comment: Thanks for your involvement and help :) but I've downgraded already to Symfony2 - imo it was a mistake to start with 3. - many useful bundles at this moment are not compatible with it and wasting time on coding complex actions by ourselves is not worth the effort I suppose.

Comment: Based on my investigation, the BeSimple's bundle do something like this (but under the hood). There would be "welcome.en/welcome.fr" compiled from "welcome" route, and if there is another route: "differentRoute" it is also stored as "differentRoute.en/differentRoute.fr". But on call in twig: "**{{ path('differentRoute') }}**" from "welcome" it would match "en" or "fr" route automatically based on the lang version of current "welcome"'s path.